# Can I restore deleted FHIR resource from _history and maintain its ID?

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir, dstu2-fhir

Most FHIR servers won't completely remove a FHIR resource from the database when you do a DELETE.

What I'm wondering is this: if I retreive the latest version of a deleted resource using it `_history` for example: `GET Patient/1/_history/2` and want to "restore" it. What's the best way to do that?

Is my only option to create a copy of the deleted patient by removing the ID and doing `POST` to `/Patient` or... is there some way to restore the deleted patient and keep its original ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may depend on the FHIR server you're using

With the HAPI FHIR server a deleted resource is still considered to be an existing record, so simply calling `PUT` on that resource will "un-delete" it and create a new version, adding it to the resource's history.

Other FHIR servers might take a different interpretation.

With the Google Cloud Healthcare API, this would require enabling the "update as create" feature, or upsert operation https://hl7.org/fhir/http.html#upsert. This feature allows you to create a resource with an ID you specify by using `PUT` instead of `POST`. The Cloud Healthcare API does not differentiate between deleted and missing records for updates, so "enableUpdateCreate" is required to "re-create" (vs "un-delete") the resource. However, even though it is "re-created", it will still become part of the resource's history.

Comment: Actually, it's not an "update as create" - it's a simple 'update'.  You're changing the content at a location that already has a record.  (A 'deleted' record is still considered to be a record.)

Comment: I've been informed that there was some discussion about this recently, and it appears that our interpretation of the spec up until this point differs from that interpretation. I edited my answer, but kept our implementation in there for completeness, rightly or wrongly.

Comment: @NikKlassen I am actually specifically trying to do this on Google Cloud's FHIR APIs. But simply doing a PUT didn't seem to work. How would I enable that?

Comment: You need to set the [enabledUpdateCreate](https://cloud.google.com/healthcare-api/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.datasets.fhirStores#:~:text=fhirStores/%7BfhirStoreId%7D.-,enableUpdateCreate,-boolean) config value on your FHIR store. Here are the docs for [editing](https://cloud.google.com/healthcare-api/docs/how-tos/fhir#editing_a_fhir_store) your FHIR store.